# R:: For all combinations of columns calculate log fold change for each row

Tags: r

I have a matrix like this:

```
mat <-  matrix(sample(0:100, 16), ncol=4)
dimnames(mat) <- list(rownames(mat, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix ="row"),
                      colnames(mat, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = "col"))
```

I would like to calculate the log fold change between all combinations of the columns, for each row. 
I can find all possible combinations of columns by using:

```
combs <- combn(colnames(mat), 2)
```

But I then want to create a data frame with log(foldchange + 1) values for each row, where the columns which are named by the comparison.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for, but please correct me if this isn't it.

I used `set.seed(1)` before defining `mat`, giving the following:

```
     col1 col2 col3 col4
row1   26   19   58   61
row2   37   86    5   33
row3   56   97   18   66
row4   89   62   15   42
```

Next I define a function to return log(foldchange + 1) of two vectors.

```
lfc1 <- function(a, b) log((b-a)/a + 1)
```

Apply the function to each pair of columns in `mat`, based on the pairs you defined in `combs`.

`logfoldchanges <- apply(combs, 2, function(col_names) lfc1(mat[, col_names[1]], mat[, col_names[2]]))`

Assign the column names of `logfoldchanges` to show which pair is compared.

`dimnames(logfoldchanges)[[2]] <- apply(combs, 2, paste, collapse = '_')`

This is the final output:

```
      col1_col2  col1_col3  col1_col4 col2_col3  col2_col4  col3_col4
row1 -0.3136576  0.8023465  0.8527773  1.116004  1.1664349 0.05043085
row2  0.8434294 -2.0014800 -0.1144104 -2.844909 -0.9578397 1.88706965
row3  0.5493593 -1.1349799  0.1643031 -1.684339 -0.3850562 1.29928298
row4 -0.3615020 -1.7805862 -0.7509668 -1.419084 -0.3894648 1.02961942
```